# How can I use a super-or-subscript tag in a HTML select option's display text?

Tags: html, unicode, html-select, subscript, superscript

I have a dropdown field like this:

```
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option> 
</select>
```

Can I use a superscript tag `<sup>` like this?

```
<select>
 <option><sup>1</sup></option>
 <option><sup>2</sup></option>
 <option><sup>2</sup></option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't use another tag inside options tag.
But you can do something like:

```html
<select>
 <option>&sup1;</option>
 <option>&sup2;</option>
 <option>&sup3;</option> 
</select>
```

This `&sub1`, `&sub2`, `&sub3` is only possible for 1, 2 and 3.

You can write other numbers using codes from here:
[Superscript Chart](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/mathchart.html#super)

Or you can use this website to get the unicodes of alphabets:
[Unicode Character Search](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm)

Comment: You can use any Unicode character like this, which means you can use the full set of numeric superscript (and subscript) numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

Answer (score 0):

### Unicode superscript/subscript codes for numbers:

```html
<p>Superscript numbers 0-9: &#x2070; &#185; &#178; &#179; &#x2074; &#x2075; &#x2076; &#x2077; &#x2078; &#x2079;</p>

<p>Subscript numbers 0-9: &#x2080; &#x2081; &#x2082; &#x2083; &#x2084; &#x2085; &#x2086; &#x2087; &#x2088; &#x2089;</p>

<select>
  <option>superscript &#x2070; &#185; &#178; &#179; &#x2074; &#x2075; &#x2076; &#x2077; &#x2078; &#x2079;</option>
  <option>subscript &#x2080; &#x2081; &#x2082; &#x2083; &#x2084; &#x2085; &#x2086; &#x2087; &#x2088; &#x2089;</option>
</select>
```