# Subscript tag not working inside HTML select tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select, subscript

I want to have chemical formula to be written inside HTML SELECT TAG.
for eg. H2O or CO2. But they should be properly formatted with subscript.
But this is not happening.

[image]

```
<select id="a1"></select>
<script>
    window.onload = function(e){
    $("#sol").css("pointer-events", "none");
    $('#a1').append("<option selected disabled>     </option><option>Trough</option><option>Beehive Shelf</option><option>Delivery Tube</option><option>Gas Jar</option><option>Thistle Funnel</option><option>MnO2 and H2O</option><option>Water</option>");
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553810/how-can-i-use-sup-sup-in-option-option-in-html/31553984

Comment: @NikitaMadeev sorry but it didn't work

Comment: I am appending the the options using javascript to the select tag

Comment: @RoboRobok please check the Code I have added